# openpyxl create new sheet assigned from other workbook

Tags: openpyxl

I am using openpyxl to edit excel files. I want put several workbooks (each workbook only has one sheet) into a final workbook and make each workbook as a sheet in the new final workbook. I used below python code. But seems `tem = ws` is not allowed.

```
import openpyxl
paths = ['path1', 'path2']
sheet_names = ['A', 'B']
wb_final = openpyxl.Workbook()
for path, sheet in zip(paths, sheet_names):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
    ws = wb.active
    tem = wb_final.create_sheet(sheet)
    tem = ws
```

Comment: What do you mean "not allowed"? You can't move worksheets between workbooks, if that's what you're hoping to do.

Comment: @CharlieClark there is an error

Comment: Please include the error in your question.